# ag-grid: agRichSelectCellEditor is not working properly in the latest version 26.2.0

Tags: javascript, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

We use the agRichSelectCellEditor to show the dropdown options. Due to the latest release 26.2.0, if users don't select an option it is showing a line instead of an empty cell. Please see the below screenshot.

[agRichSelectCellEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMP7K.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible scenario using this https://plnkr.co/edit/YY4VBakKxHRcl3Az and sharing it here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.